# How do I use Brasero to burn a movie in DVD format?

Tags: dvd, burning, brasero

I have to present an assessment for my Uni course in the form of a DVD movie (so it can be played on a DVD player) but so far, Brasero doesn't seem to be doing it. For example, I left it for over an hour today (as it said it was burning) and the DVD came out empty.

Other times, it flat out says it cannot burn the DVD. I am running Ubuntu 10.10, I have ubuntu restricted extras installed and the Medibuntu packages that allow me to watch DVDs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's right. Brasero does not make DVDs. However there are many tools around that work fine. I'd recommend [DeVeDe](http://www.rastersoft.com/programas/devede.html) (see *multiverse*) for easy doing so. Or, alternatively any other video authoring software.

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: +1 for pointing to the easiest of a set of complex tools for the job. Just to amplify, the number of video encodings is staggering, with those needed for plain old DVD viewing being among the most arcane. Putting people on the moon seems trivial compared to video transcoding and DeVeDe is a *relatively* straightforward wrapper around `mencoder` and friends.

Comment: At this point the reviews in the Software Center (and jwdinkc's comment below) suggest that DVDStyler is a much better choice.

Answer (score 5):

Other good softwares for dvd authoring are:

- [Bombono](http://www.bombono.org/cgi-bin/wiki/)
- [DVDStyler](http://www.dvdstyler.de/)

Hope you'll find useful.

Comment: I tried devede on Ubuntu 12.04. It wanted to remove several libraries before it would install. Luckily I copied the names of each library to gedit and added "sudo apt-get" in front of them. The short of it, it broke multiple video apps including totem. DVDstyler not only converted but burned in one successful swoop. That's my experience anyway.

Answer (score 3):

From https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/brasero/+bug/500947

> ```
> sudo apt-get install dvdauthor
> ```
>
> Brasero now burns DVD's!

And from https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/brasero/+question/126918

> 1. Open a terminal
> 2. Insert and run this command:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
>    ```
> 3. Try to create the DVD now.

Answer (score 2):

The question appears to concern burning rather than authoring, encoding etc. For burning a DVD I mostly use K3b.

Answer (score 1):

Totem has a plugin which does this in one click, but works not for all videos. It's pre-installed, but not enabled by default. You can enable it in Edit > Plug-ins... menu in Totem, and then use it from File menu.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can actually burn DvDs in Brasero you have to install an extra plug in called DVDauthor in the Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic.