# How can I burn a Video DVD?

Tags: video, dvd, burning

I've been trying all day to make a simple video DVD to play on a regular DVD player, but I just can't seem to figure to out. I don't understand what an image is and all the apps that I've tried today seem to use this same terminology. I tried Brasero, K3b, DeVeDe, and a few others. I have read here in the forum and in other threads that these were the ones that people seem to use. I just can't seem to create a DVD. I don't know that burning an image means or anything.

I used Windows for years and absolutely love and prefer Ubuntu now, but I just miss how easy windows software was in creating DVDs. Select a file(s) and press burn and that was it. Can some please help me out on this. I know I sound like a total noob, but I really, truly don't understand any of this burning DVDs here.....yet

Comment: also here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9575/how-do-i-use-brasero-to-burn-a-movie-in-dvd-format

Answer (score 0):

An 'image' is basically a file that describes what the contents of a disk are. You probably had to download one of these 'images' to install Ubuntu, unless you used WUBI. It looks like you want to burn a video, so I would suggest using DVD Styler, which is in the Software Center. I know that it seems complicated, but you can't just burn a video file to a DVD. It must be properly formatted, so DVD Styler will take care of all that for you.