Burning an iso of a movie makes corrupted DVDs
I tried to create a DVD of an ISO (movie). The ISO itself was created with dd (dd if=... of=...). I get no issues when playing the ISO with VLC. First I burned the ISO with Brasero. The DVD would play but without video. Using GNOME Disk Utility leads to the same issue. Last of all I tried burning the DVD with the Image Writer of Windows 7. Here the resulting DVD couldn't be detected as a movie (GNOME Disks shows that there is data, but it's marked as "unknown") and VLC/Windows Media Player/Totem freezes when trying to play it. I used a Verbatim DVD DL (the ISO size is 8.1 GB).
When I write the ISO onto a USB device, I can play the movie without any issue. I don't know if my CD/DVD-drive is corrupted, but reading DVDs/CDs and writing audio CDs makes no issues. Does anybody have an idea about what could be responsible for this?

I'm guessing that you burned the data correctly, but in order for higher-level software to detect that it is in fact a DVD with video, you should have specified that the disk is one of several DVD formats (see e.g. here). However, I'm not sure if you can do that with Brasero.

Apparently, you couldn't do that with Brasero in 2010 https://askubuntu.com/questions/9575/how-do-i-use-brasero-to-burn-a-movie-in-dvd-format

brasero detects itself what dvd type it is. I don't think that brasero is the problem. as I said, I tried other solutions as well.

That is very valuable information. Please post this as an answer.

I found the solution myself. The issue was due to css copy protection. If using dd, the copy protection is copied too. Media Players detects, that it is not the original media but that there is copy protection anyway. By using dvdbackup, you can create copies in which css is removed. Now my copy is playable.

That's exactly what I was about to write :) But I found it out yourself.

Did you was about to write „But you found it out yourself.“?
